# Hibernate отношения один-к-одному и один-ко-многим в одной сущности

Tags: java, hibernate, аннотации

Есть сущности `Audience`, `Teacher`, `Group` и `Lecture`. Сущность `Lecture` содержит одну `Audience`, одного `Teacher` и множество `Group`. Не получается с помощью аннотаций настроить маппинг, перелопатил кучу ресурсов. Что не так?

Сущность **Lecture**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lectures")
public class Lecture implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3427911934140231015L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "lecture_id")
    private Integer lectureID;

    @Column(name = "lecture_name", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String lectureName;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Audience audience;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Teacher teacher;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "lecture", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Group> groups;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "date", nullable = false, length = 7)
    private Calendar date;
```

Сущность **Audience**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "audiences")
public class Audience implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3557084992704136716L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "audience_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer audienceID;

@Column(name = "room_number", nullable = false)
private Integer roomNumber;
```

Сущность **Teacher**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teachers")
public class Teacher implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -86518201656746014L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "teacher_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer teacherID;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String lastName;
```

Сущность **Group**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2022725469824583686L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "group_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer groupID;

    @Column(name = "group_name", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String groupName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Lecture lecture;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Student.class, 
           fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
           mappedBy = "group", 
           cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Student> students;
```

Получилось настроить один к одному `Teacher`, `Audience` и `Lecture`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teachers")
public class Teacher implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -86518201656746014L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "teacher_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer teacherID;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "teacher", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Lecture lecture;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "audiences")
    public class Audience implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3557084992704136716L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "audience_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Integer audienceID;

        @Column(name = "room_number", nullable = false)
        private Integer roomNumber;

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "audience", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Lecture lecture;

        @Entity
        @Table(name = "lectures")

        public class Lecture 
                implements Serializable {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -3427911934140231015L;

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            @Column(name = "lecture_id")
            private Integer lectureID;

            @Column(name = "lecture_name", nullable = false, length = 20)
            private String lectureName;

            @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
            @JoinColumn(name="audience_id")
            private Audience audience;

            @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
            @JoinColumn(name="teacher_id")
            private Teacher teacher;
```

Comment: Я бы советовал уйти от принципа `один-к-одному и один-ко-многим` в обоих классах. Все потому что когда вы грузите в классе `Lecture` группы, в каждой `Group` есть поле `Lecture` у которого те же группы. это будет бесконечно. Сделайте или у `Lecture` есть группы, или же у `Group` есть `Lecture`.

Comment: а что именно не получается? где сущность `Student`?

Comment: при getAll из БД в lecture нет полей groups, teacher, audience

Comment: сущность Student вроде не связана с этим, поэтому не выкладывал

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Comment: при getAll из БД в lecture нет полей groups, teacher, audience. Не получается правильно расставить аннотации для мапинга

Comment: это нормально ибо у Вас стоит `FetchType.LAZY` это значит что `hibernate` загрузит эти данные по требованию, то бишь когда вы вызовете `getGroups` к примеру.

Comment: Не получается, когда я достал lecture из БД и передал в jsp, там беру обьекты, например  ${lecture.audience} и ничего не отображается

Comment: а вы до того как передать в `jsp` вызвали `getAudience`? еще как вариант (такой себе) измените `FetchType.LAZY` на `FetchType.EAGER`.

Comment: Внес поправку по teacher и audience, теперь отображаются, а Group пока нет

Comment: как я уже написал выше измените `FetchType.LAZY` на `FetchType.EAGER` для `List<Group> groups` и будут все группы сразу